# How to put an icon on the right footer of the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

How to place an icon next to an image at the bottom

I've tried using display and everything but I can't remove the icon from below the img

Comment: Hi can you provide your code to be able to help you please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this ...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-start">
                <div class="mt-5 ">
                 <img style="height: 300px; width: 300px;" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0" alt="" srcset="">
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: -7px;"><i style="font-size: 30px;margin: 0px;" class="bi bi-trash3"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```